# Intern communication platform

Tags: open-source, cms, social-networks, communication

I’m searching for a platform (online or not) to manage some info about the company.

The features we would like to have are:

- Manage clients with categories
- Simple social feature to talk with each others
- Manage files
- Share links or text to the entire company or groups

I found many things like Discourse, however it’s in Ruby. bitrix24 is the perfect example of what im looking for.

Comment: What is your point then in not using Bitrix24? Do you have any additional wishes or are you interested in alternatives? Tell us, plenty alternatives, but I would need more details from you to be able to answer this question.

Comment: If Ruby is not ok, what language are you looking for? You can check other forum software like Discourse, but client management is a bit odd. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software#General_information Of course, MediaWiki can do this as well! https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories (or Cargo), https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UploadWizard , https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:WebChat (or https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MediaWikiChat )